# Is rivulet grammatically considered as a diminutive of river?

Tags: diminutives

The word *rivulet* is not listed in [Wikipedia's list of diminutives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diminutives_by_language).
Is it considered as a diminutive of river in formal grammar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Etymologically, it is a double-diminutive. From EtymOnline:

> 1580s, from Italian rivoletto, diminutive of rivolo, itself a diminutive of rivo "brook," from Latin rivus "stream, brook," (...)

It wasn't formed into a diminutive in English, but neither was *omelette,* which you will find is on the list you linked.

However, in direct answer to your question, I would say **no.** Grammar deals with the composition of clauses, phrases, and words. It does not deal with the actual meaning of words, which I believe would be in the semantics department.

Comment: MW defines rivulet as a small stream.  But as you point out, konaya, that's not grammar, just semantics. :)

Comment: Morphology can be considered a part of grammar, and the relationship between the forms and meanings of "river" and "rivulet" is part of morphology, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So it should actually be on the list; just not under native English diminutives.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the diminutive for river can be lake or Himalayas.. If you read the definition of 'Diminutive' carefully we can understand that to reduce the size or quality of an object, to convey the smallness of the noun.. And sense of intimacy. And when you see the examples.. Like : Dog-puppies, horse-cult, hen-chick, pig-piglet, man-boy, woman-girls, duck-duckling.... SO WE can notice from above examples that all the tod of the species are considered as Diminutive.. But what about for river, hmmmm..! I have given my answers...thank you.

Comment: Puppy is not the diminutive of dog, it is the young of a dog.  This also applies to your other examples.  A river and a lake are completely different things, there are many lakes that are larger than many rivers, so your argument doesn't work.

Comment: A *cult* is a scary religious faction, not just a foal who’s grown up a bit. You meant *colt*, but even so that’s not right. Try *horsey* next time.